# SharePoint 2013 search error - no endpoint listening

Tags: sharepoint-search

Search Service Application configured shows no error while crawling. But it throws the below error while rendering results.

> "Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being
>   returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator".

If I check the logs the below exceptions are found.

> 1.Ims::Execute--Error occured: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:  There was no endpoint
>   listening at net.tcp:/QueryProcessingComponent1/ImsQueryInternal that
>   could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> 2.w3wp.exe: All query processing components are in 'Failed' status.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this error is due to date and time settings on the server.

If you have multiple servers in sharepoint farm then make sure all server have the same date and time settings.

Most importantly make sure it's allign with the domain controller server as. If date and time is different on each server then you will see that issue.
http://blog.tippoint.net/sharepoint-2013-search-stopped-working/

Comment: Hi Waqas, Thanks for your reply. But this is a single server and date and time settings are correct in the server.

Comment: What about domain controller

Comment: The domain controller has same date and time settings. The event log is not showing any error releated to data and time.